# How to catch empty string when using split length

Tags: javascript, string, split

Using the JS split function on a empty string will return 1, that makes sense of course. 
I had a situation in which I needed to count the number of ID's inside a comma-separated string. When just using `string.split(',').length` on an empty string it will return 1, which won't correspond with the actual number of ID's inside the string (but is just the default behavior of split, since a single - empty - element is returned).

To catch this, I wrote the code below. But something tells me that this isn't the most excellent solution. I would like to improve the code below and therefore get a better understanding of best practice.

Hopefully someone could help out here and provide some feedback on my issue: 
*What's the best way to count the number of ID's inside a comma-separated string, with respect to empty strings?*

```
var str1 = '12,16,91,89,43'; 
var str2 = '';

if(!str1)
  countRight = 0; 
else
  countRight = str1.split(',').length;

if(!str2)    
  countWrong = 0; 
else
  countWrong = str2.split(',').length;
```

Comment: check the length before splitted

Comment: if the result is more than zero (0), you can continue to your counter part

Comment: `split` will never "return 1". Do you mean return an array of length 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little verbose. How about

```
count = str ? str.split (',').length : 0;
```

or shorter but a little more more obscure :

```
count = +(str && str.split(',').length);
```

or even

```
count = str.length && str.split (',').length;
```

which can be shortened to

```
count = (str && str.split (',')).length;
```

Off topic : If your strings are coming from user input I would recommend allowing spaces by splitting using the regular expression `/\s*,\s*/`

Comment: Or `str.split(',').filter(Boolean).length`.

Comment: Thanks @HBP! I did ended up using you fourth solution, works like a charm and is exactly what I needed. You're absolutely right, it was verbose. But I just couldn't find out a better way to dit it, thanks to you now I do!